# Actions on Google: Request contains an invalid argument

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a Google Assistant app already in production, which gives First Aid treatment procedures whenever someone is in need. I built this app with Dialogflow. It was running well for the past few months, but now whenever I call something after the app's first statement, it gives me this error:

```
Request contains an invalid argument. 
The query pattern 'Where can I get `$SchemaOrg_Number:ordinal aid information?' 
contains an undefined parameter` (name: 'ordinal' type: 'SchemaOrg_Number').
```

This error comes when I try to implement my app from Dialogflow to Google Assistant, and from the error message, it is not clear that exactly which part of the program is faulty. I have no idea where to go from here and I'd love your help. Thanks a tonne!

[Here's my Dialogflow Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyzWw.png)

[Here's the AoG Simulator Screen where the error happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEA5R.png)

Comment: can you show some more details on the code?

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi sorry, just added. Im new in Dialogflow, please let me know any more details required.

Comment: I am not sure about the cause of the issue hence didn't reply. Can you share the code snippet of the webhook code?

Answer (score 1):

This error must have occurred due to the incorrect phrases in the Actions of your app. To check this go to **Actions** tab from the AOG console. Check every intent for any error. Also, check that the parameter used in the query must be defined below the phrases.

[Actions menu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn9Ph.png)

[Parameters screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhRCh.png)

Comment: Im sorry for replying this late, but all of my Intents except the Welcome Intent is a follow up Intent (to the Welcome Intent). There's no parameter involved in the Welcome Intent (what user enters is taken as "training phrases" in the follow up intents). Also I have about 25 follow up Intents to the Welcome Intent and none of them work. The weirder part is it used to work (and I even deployed it) some months before this issue..

Comment: try and use minimal follow-up intents. All should not be placed as follow-ups. use in-out contexts to control the intent triggering in case of similar training phrases.